# Web Api Clients Authentication (not user authentication) Best Practice

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, owin, bearer-token

I'm adding some web api to my project (using mvc web api) for our mobile clients.I'm using OWIN and Bearer Token (password grant type) for user authentication, as far as I'm concerned it's best practice for user authentication and resource authorization, **but my issue is that how I can authenticate my clients (using a standardized approach) so that only actual and real clients can have access to services (even anonymous services)**

for example we have two types of clients android and IOS apps, only these two must have access to web api

**What is the best solution (practice) for doing so and does owin have any solution for it ???**

what I've tried so far is generating a public key for each client and version and giving the keys to our mobile developers and they plug the key inside a certificate and send the key in each request

here is an example of the key for an android client

```
"StoreFrontType" : "AndroidApp"
"StoreFrontVersion" : "1.0.0.0"
"Client_Token" : "1vnM/XHDmIfv1yhftbnCnc8R92vRhSBBsciKzyHEVYmAI2bTpHqWsgmVBGel6Rd"
```

I had a conversation with our mobile developers and they said that this approach is better than nothing but **not secure enough** because **mobile apps**(specially android) source code and certificate **can be decompiled and read easily** so it's not secure enough to use my approach because by this approach if some one get the public key (by either decompiling source or reading certificate) they can send request and they will be known as a valid client

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your threat model is. There's no perfect solution for this problem. You cannot trust the mobile device to keep secret, anything identifying the device as a trusted client.

If a legitimate user of your mobile client wants to get the token/secret identifying the device as a trusted client, he/she will be able to. They could then give the identifier and token away to anyone and they would then be able to identify as a legitimate client.

If that is not a real concern for you, you could use the [OAuth2 client credentials flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.4).
OAuth2 defines the client credentials flow for clients to get access tokens on their own behalf, but this flow is only for trusted client (i.e. web applications that reside on a server).